# How do I show the soft keyboard while dismissing DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, keyboard, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to load the soft keyboard while I dismiss a DatePickerDialog. It appears to be a timing issue. The DatePickerDialog still has focus, so attempting to show the soft keyboard does nothing. However, if I use a handler to cause a delay, it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by showing the soft keyboard after a short delay. It's a hack, but it works.